# How to find ratio of two Continuous random variables

Tags: probability

A quiz is 1 hour long, and has two questions. The time you give to Q1 is represented by the
random variable $X$ which has the following pdf:
$$f_X(x)=12x(1-x)^2\qquad 0 ≤ x ≤ 1$$
The rest of the time is given to Q2. The value of $X$ is chosen based on the relative lengths of the questions.
Let $Z$ be the ratio between the time you give to the longer question and the time you give the shorter question:
Z = longer question / shorter question.
Note that Z ≥ 1.
Find P(Z ≤ 2)

This is how I have solved this.

We already know that Z has to be greater or equal to zero. So, Question 1(Longer question) will always take up more time. I am assuming here that x represents the time to get Question 1 done. And I am already given that I want Z to be between 1 and 2. So, from the ration, I get limits for Shorter Question.

Shorter Question = X/Z.
When X is 0.5 and Z is 1 then Shorter question is 0.5. Similarly when Z is 2 and X is 0.75 then Shorter question is 0.35. And then I integrate the given PDF for limits 0.5 to 0.75 and 0.35 to 0.5. I get probabilities 0.2 and 0.2 which I add up to give probability for Z. However, I am highly doubtful of my solution

Comment: I think $$Z=\frac{\max(X,1-X)}{\min(X,1-X)}$$ ,where we are given that $X\sim \text{Beta}(2,3)$.

Comment: It does make sense. What would be the limits? I hope my question isn't too naive. I am actually quite new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $X$ is the time you give to one question, the remaining time $1-X$ is given to the other question.

Going by the problem, I think we have

\begin{align}
Z=\frac{\max(X,1-X)}{\min(X,1-X)}=\begin{cases}\frac{X}{1-X}&,\text{ if }X\geqslant 1/2\\\\\frac{1-X}{X}&,\text{ if }X<1/2\end{cases}
\end{align}

So, purely mechanically, we can write (using the total probability theorem)

\begin{align}
P(Z\leqslant 2)&=P(Z\leqslant 2\,,\,X\geqslant 1/2)+P(Z\leqslant 2\,,\,X<1/2)
\\\\&=P\left(\frac{X}{1-X}\,,\,X\geqslant 1/2\right)+P\left(\frac{1-X}{X}\,,\,X<1/2\right)
\\\\&=P\left(\frac{1}{2}\leqslant X\leqslant \frac{2}{3}\right)+P\left(\frac{1}{3}\leqslant X<\frac{1}{2}\right)
\\\\&=P\left(\frac{1}{3}\leqslant X\leqslant \frac{2}{3}\right)
\\\\&=\int_{1/3}^{2/3}f_X(x)\,dx
\end{align}

According to Wolfram Alpha, the integral gives $$P(Z\leqslant 2)=\frac{13}{27}\approx 0.481481$$

There might be an easier way to do this logically.

Comment: One could look into the complement probability $P(Z>2)$ for instance and subtract $1$ from the result.